# Flutter reversed ListView start at top

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I have a `ListView` which normally starts at the top and can be scrolled down, but I have `reverse` set to `true` which is what I need it to be, but now the list starts from the bottom.

How can I set the start position so it starts at the top and scrolls down despite being reversed?

So basically it's like this, with the date order reversed like I need:

```
14th
12th
7th
6th
5th
```

But the whole thing is scrolled to the bottom by default...so I can't see 12th and 14th unless I scroll up.

```
....off the top of the screen
7th
6th
5th
4th
3rd - starting position.
```

I need it to start from the scrolled to the top by setting the scroll start position. I hope this description makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can reverse the order of presentation in this manner as well:  Note the `((feed.length-1) - index)` array index.  Using some combination of this technique and what you are using will result in what you desire.

```
List<String> feed = List();

feed.add("AAAA");
feed.add("BBBB");
feed.add("CCCC");

ListView.builder(
  itemCount: feed.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(title: feed[(feed.length - 1) - index]);
  },
);
```

Comment: Yeah that works great, thanks. It should be `(feed.length -1) - index` though. I take it there is no way to actually set a scroll start position so this workaround is fine for now.

Comment: Ok, Glad it worked out for you.  Perhaps someone can chime in with a way to set scroll position.

Comment: No this is fine for now, I have everything adjusted and working now using this method. If you fix the error I can select it as the best answer.

Comment: This is what is was looking for

Comment: This is a very simple and smart answer.

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR: `reverse: true` is for starting from the bottom.

*Don't use it for starting from the top.*

I learnt: `reverse: true` isn't for reversing the items in your **list**, it's for reversing the **scroll direction**. It seemed really convenient for reversing your items, but it's not as convenient as `list.reversed.toList()`. Therefore, it doesn't make sense that you'd want to "start from the top", but also use `reverse: true` (start from the bottom).

- If you want your items reversed, them reverse them:

```dart
final cats = [Cat("Winston"), Cat("Bournville")];
final reversedCats = cats.reversed.toList();
// Use the reversed list: e.g. set state, etc.
```

See [docs on `reversed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/reverse.html):

> Similarly, if
> [scrollDirection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/scrollDirection.html)
> is
> [Axis.vertical](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Axis.html),
> then the scroll view scrolls from top to bottom when
> [reverse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/reverse.html)
> is false and **from bottom to top** when
> [reverse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/reverse.html)
> is true.

**Side note:** I would avoid indexing your list in the builder though like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499656/7365866), seems like it would be **error prone**. Also, your state doesn't match your ListView. If you're debugging, 10 of 30 on your ListView would be 20 of 30 in your state.

**Another side note:** I did try `reverse: true` and then set a `ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: double.maxFinite)`, but this doesn't work very well.

Answer (score -1):

After placing data in list,just use reversed property of iterable(list).

```
List<int> i = List();
i.add(3);
i.add(5);
i.add(8);
for (int j  in i.reversed) {
  print('$j');
}
```